# Export using EEexcelviw to big data does't work

Tags: gridview, yii, export

I am currently using EEexcelview (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eexcelview/) to export my files. I tried to export 40,000 rows but itsn't working. Is there a limit or something? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working"? Do you get any error? If so - please post them. And best would be to post the code that occurs this error as well.

Comment: it doesn't post any error, i mean all i can see is blank page but when i try to export 1,000 rows it is working

Comment: I suppose that you work with php? Did you set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(-1);`?

Comment: Yes. I think my problem is about memory but i'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: Did you get a solution? Please post your code how you do your export. I guess you try to get 40.000 at once and save it in a variable - that won't work because of your memory - but step by step should work.